# How to use Python requests and looping to write Json files

Tags: python, json, python-requests, python-3.5

I have writen some python code o help me pull data from an API. The first version of my program work quite well.

N0w i am trying to develop a more DRY version of the code by introducing functions and loops  . I am still new to python.

Your proffesional advice will be really apreciated

```
import requests
import json  

# Bika Lims Authentication details

username = 'musendamea'
password = '!Am#2010@bgl;'

# API url Calls for patients, analysis and   cases

patient_url = "adress1"
analysis_url = "adress2"
cases_url = "adress3"

# peform API calls and parse json data

patient_data = requests.get(patient_url, auth=(username, password ))
analysis_data = requests.get(analysis_url, auth=(username, password ))
cases_data = requests.get(cases_url, auth=(username, password ))

patients = json.loads(patient_data.text)
analysis = json.loads(analysis_data.text)
cases = json.loads(cases_data.text)

# checks for errors if any
print ("Patients")
print (patients['error'])
print (patients['success'])
print (patients['last_object_nr'])
print (patients['total_objects'])

print ("\n Analysis")
print (analysis['error'])
print (analysis['success'])
print (analysis['last_object_nr'])
print (analysis['total_objects'])

print ("\n Cases")
print (cases['error'])
print (cases['success'])
print (cases['last_object_nr'])
print (cases['total_objects'])

# create and save json files for patients, analysis and cases

with open('patients.json', 'w') as outfile:
json.dump(patients['objects'], outfile)

with open('analysis.json', 'w') as outfile1:
json.dump(analysis['objects'], outfile1)

with open('cases.json', 'w') as outfile2:
json.dump(cases['objects'], outfile2)
```

The Above code works pretty well but my challenge is making the code DRY. somehow the loop breaks when i change the following section

```
your_domain = "10.0.0.191"
data_types = ['patients', 'analysis', 'cases']
checkers = ['error', 'success', 'total_objects']
urls = []
data_from_api = []

# API url Call
base_url = "http://" + your_domain + "/@@API/read?"
page_size = "1000000000000000000"

patient_url = base_url + "catalog_name=bika_patient_catalog&page_size="
            + page_size
analysis_url = base_url + "portal_type=AnalysisRequest&
            review_state=published&page_size=" + page_size
cases_url = base_url + "portal_type=Batch&page_size=" + page_size

urls.append(patient_url)
urls.append(analysis_url)
urls.append(cases_url)

# peform API calls and parse json data
def BikaApiCalls(urls, username, password):
    for i in len(urls):
         data_ = requests.get(urls[i - 1], auth = (username, password))
        print (data_types[i] + " ~ status_code: ")
        print (data_.status_code + "\n")
        data_from_api.append(json.loads(data_.text))
        for val in len(checkers):
            print (data_from_api[i][val])
BikaApiCalls(urls, username, password)

# Write JSON files
def WriteJson(data_types, data_from_api):
    for i in len(data_from_api):
        with open(data_types[i] + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data_from_api[i]['objects'], outfile)

WriteJson(data_types, data_from_api)
```

Where am I getting it wrong. I tried some debugging but i ca seen to get through. Id really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Exception details please? Give us some more detail!

Comment: I see an indentation problem in the for loop in your BikaApiCalls method.

Comment: Your problem description is too broad. You should provide more specific issue as you cannot ask questions like "Here is my code. What is wrong with it?" or "Give some advices to improve my code"

Comment: @aurthur-musendame, you really should consider deleting your "Bika Lims Authentication details" and any other personal credentials from questions as this is a public post